# How can I return only English results from Amazon's Product Advertising API?

Tags: php, amazon-product-api

I was wondering if I could get some help regarding Amazon's [Product Advertising API (formerly ECS)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html) - I need to be able to return results of the English language only, but the code below returns books in a variety of languages.

```
$response = $amazonEcs->country('co.uk')->category('Books')->responseGroup('Large')->search('php');
```

Example of returned result:

> "Ruby on Rails: Einstieg in die effiziente Webentwicklung. Mit Ajax /
>   Web 2.0 PHP-Vergleich und Ruby-EinfÃ¼Ehrung"

I am using PHP.

Thanks in advance - any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change

`$amazonEcs->country('co.uk')->category('Books')->`

to

`$amazonEcs->country('com')->category('Books')->`